# How to pass a value from one view to another view

Tags: iphone, ios

I have two views of two subpages. Here I want to pass the value from one sub class of view to another. I searched the web, but can't find a clear answer. Can anybody provide an example for passing a `UITextField` value from one to another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain a common string in appDelegate.

Define a string

```
 NSString *commString;
```

in appDelegate.

And then when you submit the uitextfield value just assign that text field value to the

```
appDelegate.commString
```

use this in the next view.

```
ProjectNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplicatoin] delegate];
appDelegate.commString = textField.text;
```

This will work for sure.

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to suggest, if it isnt what you're looking for ill post another similar solution but this is what you're asking. Nice one Mohan

Comment: Add NSString *commString; in projectAppDelegate .h file, then declare property in the file. Synthesis the string in .m file @synthesis commString;  add commString = [[NSString alloc] init]; in the app delegate launch method. Then this string to store the text field value. Store the text field value when you submit the form. In the action method add addDelegate.commString = textField.text;  Before that

Comment: add ProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] delegate]; Then you can use the appDelegate .commString where ever you want.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIApplication sharedApplicatoin]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x8631d4'

       Its shown in console error.